# Hint for proof of $\mathrm e^π>π^{\mathrm e}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I found a [collection of "challenging" calculus questions](https://www.math.unl.edu/~mrammaha1/Challenging%20problems/Challenge-Problems.pdf), and the first is this:

> Prove that
>   $$e^\pi > \pi^e$$
>   *Hint: Take the natural log of both sides and try to define a suitable function
>   that has the essential properties that yield [the] inequality.*

Taking $ln$ of both sides gets $$\pi > e \cdot \ln(\pi)$$

I thought of replacing the $\pi$ with $\arccos(-1)$ for $$-1 > \cos(e \cdot \ln(\pi))$$ and then maybe $f(x) = \cos(e \cdot \ln(x))$, but I have no idea where to go from there, or if that's the right direction. Can anyone offer hints as to the next steps?

Comment: All possible proofs are discussed under this question, and a dozen of its duplicates.